# Inconsistencies of ObservableObject with variable declaration

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I m new to swift and I would like to understand an error that I m getting with this declaration:

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int

    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String
}
```

With this declaration:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user = User()
}
```

I m getting:

`Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call`

`Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'`

While with this one I m getting no errors:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user = [User]()
}
```

Comment: You are not using any of the init methods that the compiler has created for you (one with parameters for all the properties and one used for Codable) for the User struct but one without parameters. In the second case you are using a valid, existing init for Array. I could explain more but I think the best thing is for you to learn more about init methods because they are quite an essential part of swift programming

Comment: the only point I don't understand is that why it doesn't throw an error when it's an array!

Comment: You should read [this chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) about initializers in the Swift Programming Language book

Comment: Because you are not creating any User objects, you are creating an empty array in the second example

Answer (score 0):

You need explicit initializer for this case, like

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int

    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String

   init(id: Int = 0, firstName: String = "", lastName: String = "") {
      self.id = id
      self.first_name = firstName
      self.last_name = lastName
   }
}
```